# \usepackage{graphicx} prevents document from compiling

Tags: graphics

I am trying to to add some graphs to my current work. The graphs are png graphic format and are saved in the same file as my tex-document.
The problem is, that adding the `\usepackage{graphicx}` cause texmaker to shut down the compiling to pdf.  I downloaded the most recent updates on Miktex and installed the newest version of texmaker, but somehow it still does not work.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,onecolumn,oneside]{article}


\usepackage[left=5cm,right=2cm,top=2cm,bottom=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[onehalfspacing]{setspace}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage[nottoc]{tocbibind}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage{cases}

\begin{figure}
\includegraphics[scale=4cm]{Dokument.png}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: your example produces the errors `! LaTeX Error: Missing \begin{document}.` and  `! Undefined control sequence.
<recently read> \includegraphics`

Answer (score 4):

`scale` takes a number, not a length, as argument. If you want to set the width of the image to 4cm, use

```
\includegraphics[width=4cm]{image}
```

`scale` is used to scale an image by a given factor, for example with

```
\includegraphics[scale=2]{image}
```

the image becomes twice its natural size.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,onecolumn,oneside]{article}
\usepackage[left=5cm,right=2cm,top=2cm,bottom=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[onehalfspacing]{setspace}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage[nottoc]{tocbibind}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage{cases}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\includegraphics{example-image}

\includegraphics[scale=0.5]{example-image}

\includegraphics[width=4cm]{example-image}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Note by the way that it is *not* required to use a `figure` environment to insert images. The purpose of a `figure` is to allow for (numbered) captions to images, and to let LaTeX move the image around to get better page breaks, so you're not left with a half empty page because the image didn't fit, for example.  (You were perhaps aware of it but it happens that people use a `figure` when they shouldn't.)